# Difficulty importing ThemedTK from ttkthemes

Tags: python, ttk

I'm trying to import ThemedTK from ttkthemes in Python3 but am getting the following error message:

line 4, in 
from ttkthemes import Themed_TK
ImportError: cannot import name 'Themed_TK' from 'ttkthemes'

Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTK
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from draw import bellGen

root = ThemedTK()
```

Comment: What exactly are you importing? In the error message: `Themed_TK`. In the code: `ThemedTK`. It is very likely that you are simply using the wrong class name.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I think the error message is just ThemedTK - not Themed_TK. I'm just attempting to use the code from the following page but am having no luck so far. https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html

Comment: Error message I'm getting:

Comment: '''from ttkthemes import ThemedTK
ImportError: cannot import name 'ThemedTK' from 'ttkthemes' '''

Comment: Do you have a `ttkthemes.py` file in the same directory as your script? Same name as ttkthemes package. Or maybe you named the script file itself ttkthemes.py.

Comment: No, not all - the only ttkthemes files I have are the ones I did a pip install for. Here: python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/RedFantom/ttkthemes

Comment: The file directory for this file only has my own code.

Comment: Try `from ttkthemes import ThemedTK` in PythonShell/IDLE.

Comment: Here's the PythonShell Output:

Comment: Python 3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:10:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from ttkthemes import ThemedTK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from ttkthemes import ThemedTK
ImportError: cannot import name 'ThemedTK' from 'ttkthemes' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ttkthemes/__init__.py)
>>>

Comment: And just in case, the contents of the init file (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ttkthemes/__init__.py`) are the same as the [source code](https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkthemes/blob/master/ttkthemes/__init__.py)? And all the other files are there and correspond to the sources (themed_tk.py, themed_style.py).

Comment: I don't see such a pattern, `pip install git+github.com/RedFantom/ttkthemes`, in the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/). Anyway, try uninstalling and reinstalling the package (for example, from PyPI).

Comment: Ok, so I've checked the installation and that's all fine according to the source code.

Comment: themed_tk.py has been installed in which exists the class ThemedTK.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's `ThemedTk`. With lowercase "k".

Here's the documentation for it: [ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html](https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html)

Comment: good reply, but could use a source: https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html.